# Как получить последнюю ссылку?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Пытаюсь получить ссылку от голосового сообщения ВКонтакте. При переходе на неё, появляется другая ссылка, которую нужно получить.
Что я пробовал сделать:

```
opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
request = urllib.request.Request('https://vk.com/doc67915235_476512804')
u = opener.open(request)
print(u.geturl())
```

В итоге возвращается опять эта же ссылка: https://vk.com/doc67915235_476512804 а нужно, чтобы возвращалась: https://psv4.userapi.com/c852436//u67915235/audiomsg/d4/495669fb43.ogg

Comment: А что происходит при загрузке https://vk.com/doc67915235_476512804? Переход на ссылку с .ogg? Или сам файл находится на странице и вы хотите до его ссылки добраться?

Comment: @gil9red когда открываю эту ссылку https://vk.com/doc67915235_476512804 в обычном браузере, то переходит на ссылку с .ogg
Как получить ссылку .ogg в python? Изначальная ссылка всегда будет разной

Comment: Нужно смотреть что приходит, мб там js-код, который делает переход на другую ссылку, мб та ссылка возвращает редирект и в заголовке ответа указывает ссылку на переход

Comment: @gil9red и как можно узнать? Вручную что-то не получается, т.к. переход происходит моментально

Comment: Смотреть что пришло в `u` -- на саму страницу, на заголовки. Или открыть в барузере инструмент разработчика (F12) и смотреть какие запросы по сети были

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать метод API docs.getById.
Туда нужно подать docs=67915235_476512804

Тут документация про параметр: https://vk.com/dev/docs.getById
А тут о том, как делать запросы к API: https://vk.com/dev/api_requests

Comment: Ну, мне помог метод messages.getById